# How to have .on('click') event in a JS class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, javascript-objects, html5-audio

I am making a HTML5 audio player and I have a file as module that manages audio element and in the main JS file I will import it for the functionalities I need.
In this module I want to have codes like `$(audio).on("playing", function(){...})`.

I made a simple JS class as below

"use strict"

```
class AudioManager{
    constructor(audio) {
        this.audio = audio;
    }

    $(audio).on("playing", function1());
    $(audio).on("pause", function2());
    $(audio).on("ended", function3());

}

export default AudioManager;
```

The above code as syntax error.
Can you please how I can re-code this correctly.

In my main js code, I will call this class and give it the audio element and let this class to take care of the audio and manage it base on how I define it on this class.

like below:
`let myAudio = new AudioManager(audio);`
So the class will know what to do with this audio when ended or when on pause.

Comment: You have not tagged this `jquery`, nor mentioned jQuery in the question, but you are using jQuery-like syntax. You can do this without jQuery simply by using `addEventListener`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, Isn't the bigger problem here the fact that he is trying to place those event handlers inside the class..

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev That is why it's not an answer...

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason for your syntax error:

```
$(audio).on("playing", function1());
```

should be

```
$(audio).on("playing", function1);

function function1() {
    //function code here
}
```

or

```
$(audio).on("playing", function() {
    //function code here
});
```

Comment: This did now help. The issue is the events are not inside a function. for example the following works `func = function(audio){
        $(audio).on("playing", somefunc);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring all the codes below to `constructor`:

```
$(audio).on("playing", function1());
$(audio).on("pause", function2());
$(audio).on("ended", function3());
```